# Alertdialog with custom layout button

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I have a layout for my alertdialog.And there is a button to call timepicker.
But I don't know how to write the button's setonClickListener.
It always crashed.

**FATAL EXCEPTION: main**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at prototype.feedme.cat.prototype.activity.CatActivity$3.onClick(CatActivity.java:115)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**Code:**

```
private Button time;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.CatActivity);
    time=(Button)findViewById(R.id.time);
    time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimePickerDialog tpd=new TimePickerDialog(CatActivity.this, mTimesetlistener, mHour, mMinute, true);
            tpd.show();
        }
    });
    clk_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(CatActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Hi")
                    .setMessage("Are you ok?")
                    .setView(R.layout.notificaton_setting)
                    .show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the crash logs please

Comment: You don't initialize `clk_btn` which causes the crash (`NullPointerException`) when you set the `OnClickListener`. Use `findViewById(int)` to initialize the button

Comment: @arthur_gg I posted it . Thank you!

Comment: can you show your xml? is the id ( R.id.time ) of the button correct?

Comment: the time button is in R.layout.notificaton_setting. how can I code it correctly?

Comment: yeas the system will look into CatActivity layout to find the button. you can add another time button xml in you CatActivity layout

Comment: but I need to put the button in that layout so I can click it when calling dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that the button is inside dialog. But you try to find it in activity. I mean that until you try to show your dialog there it no the button at all and you try to find it from activity onCreate method.

What you need to do is to find your button in Dialog view. You can do it this way:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notificaton_setting, null);
dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.time).setOnClickListener(...)

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

Comment: oh. It doesn't crash now. Very thank you.
But I don't know why I click that button and nothing happens...

Comment: Works :  l1 = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.l1);, but not work setOnClickListener... from l1

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `clk_btn` before you call setOnClickListener

```
private Button time;
private Button clk_btn; //<-- ADD THIS
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);
time=(Button)findViewById(R.id.time);
time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TimePickerDialog tpd=new TimePickerDialog(CatActivity.this, mTimesetlistener, mHour, mMinute, true);
        tpd.show();
    }
});
clk_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID) //<-- AND ADD THIS
clk_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("Hi")
                .setMessage("Are you ok?")
                .setView(R.layout.notificaton_setting)
                .show();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: oh I added it but I didn't post it.

Comment: still crash. I think the problem is on time.setOnClickListener

Comment: Are you sure that the buttons exist in `R.layout.MainActivity`? If not, findViewById will return null

Comment: the time button is in R.layout.notificaton_setting. how can I find it?

Comment: Either not use the button there or inflate that layout